# Yii Grid Column Value

Tags: content-management-system, yii

I have 2 models: 1 for the Website, 1 for the Product;

the product knows that he belong to website x; in table product i have website_id

In Product i have the relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
                'relation_website' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Website','website_id'),
    );
}
```

in the view admin of the Product model i have:

```
$dataProvider = $model->search();
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 100;

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'product-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'product',
        'price',
        'currency',
        array(
        'name' => 'website_id',
        'value' => $model->relation_website->website_id,
        ),
        /*
          'website_id',
          'url_id',
         */
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{update}{delete}',
        ),
    ),
));
```

i now have this result:

1   Laptop Acer Aspire V3-571G-73614G50Maii cu procesor IntelÂ® CoreTM i7-3610QM 2.30GHz, Ivy Bridge, 4GB, 500GB, nVidia GeForce GT 640M 2GB, Linpus, Black 3099.99 RON 1 <- this value here

instead of the last 1 i want to print http://www.eshop.com/, value stored in website table, table that belongs to the Website model

1   Laptop Acer Aspire V3-571G-73614G50Maii cu procesor IntelÂ® CoreTM i7-3610QM 2.30GHz, Ivy Bridge, 4GB, 500GB, nVidia GeForce GT 640M 2GB, Linpus, Black 3099.99 RON http://www.domain.com/

Comment: never mind, i figured it out: 'value' => '$data->relation_website->website',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something like:

```
...
'value' => '$data->relation_website->name'
...
```

There is a similar example in the [blog tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/post.admin#listing-posts-in-tabular-view) which is a MUST READ For every Yii developer

Comment: i was looking for chtml :)) 10x